# code for search bar by using if else statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dont know how to resolve this problem. i need a code for search bar.i.e, if i enter "abc" in search bar..it should display the function lhr().

This is the onclick function:

```
<script>
    function lhr(){
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="abc";
        document.getElementById("xy").innerHTML="<BR>x°N , y°E";
    }
</script>
<script>
    function kara(){
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="abc";
        document.getElementById("xy").innerHTML="<BR>x°N , y°E";
    }
</script>
```

this is the div where function lhr() and kar() called

```
<div class="b" id="menu">
    <li onclick="lhr()"><p1>L</p1></li>
    <li onclick="kara()"><p1>K</p1></li>
</div>
```

Then i insert search bar in the same div

```
<input value="SEARCH" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" style="margin-left: 15px;" /><input id="myInput" type="text" >

<div id="display"></div>
```

now i want to run the search bar in a way that when i enter "L" in the bar the function of lhr() excecutes

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
   var input;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (input==L){
       document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=lhr();
         }
        else if (input==K){
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=kara();
      }
       document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = myFunction();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to listen for the events on the input. Also, you need to look for keycodes (http://keycode.info/), not actual letters. this should get you started https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/ndvf3cxm/

Comment: As mentioned by @VilleKoo, you need to listen for the input in the element 'serach bar' in your case. But if you need to handle it on click then I guess below answer will help.

Comment: not helping. i need code without jquery

Comment: @FatimaMushtaq did you check the fiddle? No jQuery there...

Comment: oh yes. thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```js
function lhr(){
  $("#result").empty();
  $("#result").append("lhr is running"); 
}
function kara(){
  $("#result").empty();
  $("#result").append("kara is running");
}

function search(){
  if($("#input").val()=="" || $("#input").val()==undefined ){
    $("#result").empty();
    $("#result").append("No Result Found");
  }else if($("#input").val()=="L"){
  lhr();
  }else if($("#input").val()=="K"){
  kara();
  }else{
  $("#result").empty();
    $("#result").append("No Result Found");
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input"> <button type="button"  onclick="search()">Search</button>

<div >
<p>Search Result</p>
<div id="result">

</div>
</div>
```